# Powershell 4 piping & Get-Printer interaction

Tags: powershell, printing, powershell-4.0, piping, network-printers

I am attempting to write a short script that will get a list of all of the computers in the domain and then run Get-Printer on them to obtain a list of all of the installed printers on each machine.

To obtain the list of computers in the domain I would like to use "net view" so I tried

```
net view | ForEach-Object {Get-Printer -ComputerName $_}
```

But that does not work. Instead I just get a line of "spooler service is not reachable" for each PC in net view.

Manually entering the pc names into "Get-Printer" works perfectly and I actually wrote a working script that outputs the results of net view to a .txt file after searching for PC names in the text, then it reads each line from the text file and inputs them sequentially into "Get-Printer". But I would like to be able to expand upon this code to centrally manage the printers so I need to get this working from one line which I think is possible.

Can anyone explain what I am missing here? How does ForEach actually work in Powershell 4?

The following is my working code that writes to a file and then reads from it:

```
$PCs = net view /all | Select-String "\\"

$a = ForEach ($Line in $PCs)

{   $Line -Replace(" ","")

}

$a | Out-file -FilePath C:\Users\esmith\Desktop\test.txt -Encoding ascii

Get-content C:\Users\esmith\Desktop\test.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-Printer -cn $_} | Out-file -FilePath C:\Users\esmith\Desktop\output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`net view` is a DOS command line, which returns text output. The PowerShell pipeline works on objects instead of text, so that does not combine well in this case. (Technically: strings are objects as well, but not the kind of objects that you expect here).

You can use the native PowerShell cmdlet [`Get-AdComputer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx) to obtain a list of the domain joined computers as PowerShell objects, which you can then feed into the pipeline.

Something like this should work:

```
Get-AdComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object { Get-Printer -ComputerName $_.Name }
```

[The `Get-Printer` cmdlet does except pipeline input directly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918358(v=wps.620).aspx), so this should work as well (without the need for an explicit ForEach-Object):

```
Get-AdComputer -Filter * | Get-Printer
```

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense & explains why my workaround was effective. I have a new problem however; It seems that running your code is successful until I hit a machine without the printer spooler service running. Then it hangs indefinitely. Is there some way to add a timeout to that query and move on to the next pc in the list? This issue wasn't present with my workout code because Get-AdComputer returns a much larger list of devices than net view does including many that aren't running the spooler service.

Comment: Get-Printer does not seem to support a timeout parameter. I would expect it to have reasonable timeout value built in. Are you sure it does never return, or does just take (too) long? If you use my second example, then Get-Printer can do multiple calls at the same time, which will workaround delays.